# Can a Public LoadBalancer or App Gateway redirect traffic to Private LoadBalancer

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, internal-load-balancer

Hi community I've been trying to connect a public load balancer or app gateway to a private load balancer or do you guys know another way to handle that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to traffic from Application Gateway to Internal LB.
Application Gateway support backends:

- Public IP addresses
- Internal IP addresses
- FQDN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-components#backend-pools

Here is document that describes how to configure Application Gateway with Internal LB as a backend.

https://renjithmenon.com/application-gateway-with-internal-load-balancer-configuration/

Comment: But it means you cannot redirect traffic from load balancer to another load balancer ?
still dont find a way to do it :(

Comment: It is possible, did you try this way?
https://renjithmenon.com/application-gateway-with-internal-load-balancer-configuration/

Comment: Amazing but as you can see its only related to App Gateway to loadbalancer and not loadbalancer to another loadbalancer maybe the way you describe its the way to go